# vba access access table to sql server

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an `MS access 2010` file with a lot of tables. This information needs to be written to `SQL server`.

This seems easy but I’m stuck on this peace of code;

```
stSQL = "INSERT INTO sqltablename ([sqlcolumn_name]) VALUES ('test') "
```

I guess I must replace test for a link to a column in one of my tables, but how can I fix it without typing any (very) long peace of code?

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably need to give a little bit more information..

I would assume you want to write information from an Access table to a linked SQL Server table.. you can easily write an Access query that appends to the SQL Server linked table, that should suit your needs.